# The possibility of non-carbon-based lifeforms

Tags: universe

Given what we know now. My understanding is that all life requires the combustion of oxygen and expelling carbon dioxide. Could it be possible in any form then that anything exists that is not carbon-based, and not science-fiction of course.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it isn't a question about physics

Comment: Hi Marlon. I'm not sure whether this is chemistry or biology (I guess it's biochemistry) but it's not something we physicists are going to know about. Maybe ask on the Biology Stack Exchange?

Comment: By the way: Even on earth there are many [anaerobic organisms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anaerobic_organism) which don't require combustion of oxygen.

Comment: Thanks, I was not sure whether it was physics oriented or otherwise. Will rephrase and re-ask on the correct platform, my apologies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My understanding is that all life requires the combustion of oxygen
>   and expelling carbon dioxide

This is not correct, we have known since the 1600's there are many life forms on Earth that [do not use oxygen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anaerobic_organism) cycles. In fact, they were all the life on Earth until the [cyanobacteria](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyanobacteria) poisoned the atmosphere with oxygen, at which point the anaerobic life was wiped out in one of the [greatest mass extinctions in the history of the planet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_Oxygenation_Event).

> Could it be possible in any form then that anything exists that is not
>   carbon-based

This is an unrelated question, we don't breath oxygen because we're carbon-based, and as I note above, you can be carbon-based and not breath oxygen.

Carbon is a good candidate for life simply because it can *easily* create so many complex molecules. There are lots of other complex molecules, but generally speaking, there's no basic building block to all of them like carbon.

[Several alternatives have been proposed over time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypothetical_types_of_biochemistry), but they all have problems. Given how widespread carbon is, one can also argue that anywhere that has the conditions needed for, say, silicon-based life likely could have carbon-based life too, and in that case, simple statistics argues the carbon would happen first. So just as anaerobic organisms have been pushed into niches because of oxygen breathers, one would expect these other forms of life would also be pushed into niches due to the existence of carbon. This is the subject of much argument.